# how to monitor apache load balancer nodes

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, ajp

I have apache load balancer doing load balancing via tomcat servers ajp as follows:

```
    Worker URL  Route   RouteRedir  Factor  Set Status  Elected To  From
    ajp://localhost:8009/myapp  s1      2   0   Ok  2292     0   22M
    ajp://xx.xx.xx.64:8009/myapp    s2      2   0   Ok  2291     0   23M
    ajp://xx.xx.xx.228:8009/myapp   s3      2   0   Ok  2292     0   23M
    ajp://xx.xxx.xx.242:8009/myapp  s4  1   0   Ok  2121     0   21M
```

Sometimes the status results in Error,  is there a way I can monitor this constantly and get an email notification if it happens?

Comment: you probably need to use some monitoring tool or poll the status page continuously, Apache itself does not come with much monitoring functionality itself.